# Android Cursor.getString(int) stuck

Tags: java, android, sql

Whenever I call this function, it stucks, I was able to trace back the line where it stucks but I'm new to android development and even to Java so I don't know what's wrong.

```
public Movie getMovie( int id ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MOVIES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    else
        return null;

    //Create new movie object and fill it with data from the db
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setId( Integer.parseInt( cursor.getString(0) ) );
    movie.setTitle( cursor.getString(1) );
    movie.setDescription( cursor.getString(2) );

    return movie;
}
```

The `Movie` class changes the title, id etc. only if the argument is not empty or `null`. So an empty movie has a default title "Unknown." and if I call `setTitle( "" )` it won't change.

So whatever happens to the data I get from the database, it has always a title. But when I try to set an id, the `cursor` stucks. Nothing happens. Anyone knows why? Also, yes I get a readable database and the cursor is not null. It stucks in the line with `setId()`.

Comment: That seems unlikely.  Have you walked through it in a debugger and done a step into?  Are you sure it isn't finding some infinite loop in your setId code?

Comment: @GabeSechan Well the code I have written does not have an infinite loop. It's just a simple setter method for my Movie class. I checked that. I'll try a debugger again but the last time I did not find anything.

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks. I got this from a tutorial, I am not familiar with the cursor class. But it still gets stuck. Even when I comment the id line out, the other two lines get stuck as well and they are strings.

Comment: Do you get an error, in your LogCat? If so, post it and let's analyze it.

Comment: Are you sure it is getting stuck, and not throwing an exception? Do you have LogCat output?

Comment: @DerGolem Nope, I get nothing.

Comment: @cfred yeah, the function is getting called when I click a button. But this button is still clickable and the program is still working.

Comment: @DerGolem I restarted eclipse. I don't know why but now it works...

Answer (score 0):

I got this and scratched my head for half an hour.

`cursor.getString(0)` was throwing (and thus seemed stuck) because it had no result. I didn't check that `cursor.moveToFirst()` was `true`.

I never saw the exception as this was code that was called by an exception handler. Yay.

You have the same error in your code, remember to check moveToFirst:

```
if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst())
    return null;
cursor.getString(0);
```